# What are the normal forms of valediction (signing off letters and emails) in Chinese?

Tags: writing, equivalent-phrase, phrase

For example, how do they normally sign off letters?  We normally use 'Yours Faithfully' or 'Your Sincerely' but we might not be so formal in emails and instead just 'Regards'.

What is standard practise in Chinese for both letters/emails?

Comment: *What is standard practise in Chinese for both letters/emails?*--  Email is usually more casual, just a signature at the end is enough.  unless it is a formal letter in Email form, then we treat it the same as a letter.

Answer (score 6):

**謹上** or **敬上** is fairly common. Your own name precede this closing term, contrary to English.

Comment: simple answer for simple question is proper, long winded answer actually confuse people

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the formality of the letter or email, the age of person being addressed, his/her relationship to you and how familiar you are with the said person. This is not something that you can define or quantify - you just have to get a feel for it.

Anyway, for letters, the standard valediction goes something like this:

```
  此致 
敬礼!
```

Note the double space before 此致. This is used for someone you don't know (well) and is very respectful.

Once you have acquired a certain degree of acquaintenance with the person, then you can write pretty much anything that one considers respectful such as

- 身体健康
- 万事如意
- 工作顺利

or even:

- 谢谢

Just to list a few.

For emails, the same rules apply; but since they are much more casual, sometimes people don't include any valediction at all. Just type the body and hit send.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a late answer to this question. But I'd like to add more details based on deutschZuid's answer.

```
  此致  
敬礼！
```

is the most common and always right like **regards** in English. But usually it's for private letter. If you are writing a letter to business companion, you can use:

```
        顺祝
    商祺!
```

or

```
        祝
    生意兴隆！
```

Answer (score 0):

You should say "学业有成" for the junior “桃李满天下”for your teacher

Comment: What do you mean by 'junior'?